# Scroll Tabs in RTL mode

Tags: react-native, npm, tabs, right-to-left

I have `Tabs` from `mui` version 5 library. I want to show a scroll button if it's needed and when I click it, it goes to the left side. My project is in `rtl` mode. The button shows on the left side and when I click on it, it moves to the right side. I think it doesn't get `rtl` mode. I've searched but I couldn't find a solution. Below are my codes. Please check it and if you can, help me.

```
<Box sx={{ margin: '1.9vh',direction:"rtl"}}>
  <Box  >
    {/* */}
    <Tabs
      variant="scrollable"
      scrollButtons="auto"
      ScrollButtonComponent={MyTabScrollButton}

      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid #C1C7CB" }}
      TabIndicatorProps={{
        style: {
          background: "#01af43",
          top: 0,
          height: "4px ",

        },
      }}
    >
    .
    .
    </Tabs>
    </Box>
    </Box>
```